# Contacts storage in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, multiautocompletetextview

I am Building an app where a Dialog box pops up when a button is clicked in an activity and the Dialog Box contain a MultiAutoCompleteTextview to select contacts in the form of contactname%number,contactname1%number,contactname2%number...

so now i am stuck at a place where i have to store the individual contacts by spliting the MultiAutoCompleteTextview using the comma "," and storing them one by one in an string array named "arrayOfString".

Next i want to split the name and the contact no using % in between them and store all contactnumbers and only contactnumbers without names in sharedpreferences one by one using a string "setnum".

but the app is crasing and reloading when i click the positivebutton save with the code below

Initilizations:

```
    SharedPreferences sp;
SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
String setnum="";
```

code:

```
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           String[] arrayOfString=localMultiAutoCompleteTextview.getText().toString().split(",");
            int i=0;
            if(i>=arrayOfString.length){
                System.out.println("**********************" + setnum);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), setnum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sp=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("sdat", 2);
                ed=sp.edit();
                ed.putString("snum", setnum);
                ed.commit();
                setnum="";
                getActivity().finish();
                return;
            }
           String str2="";
            if(arrayOfString[i].contains("%"))
                str2 = arrayOfString[i].split("%")[1];
            String str1;
            for (setnum=(setnum+str2+",");;setnum=(setnum+str1+",")) {
                i++;
                str1 = arrayOfString[i]; /*i am getting error here*/
            }
        }
    });
```

i am getting the error at forth line from last at str1 = arrayOfString[i];

log:

```
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
        at com.sharat.emin3m.antirag.ContactDialog$1.onClick(ContactDialog.java:75)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5354)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

plz help me with the code for my miniproject in college. thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the increment like below.

```
for (setnum=(setnum+str2+",");i<arrayOfString.length;setnum=(setnum+str1+",")) {
    str1 = arrayOfString[i++]; /*error solved here*/
}
```

**Reason:**
`i` is incremented before the usage.
Set exit condition in the `for` loop

**Edit:**
This is the complete code for your use case.

```
String[] arrayOfString=localMultiAutoCompleteTextview.getText().toString().split(",");
sp=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("sdat", 2);
ed=sp.edit();

// Get already stored numbers from preference
String oldNumbers = sp.getString("snum", new JSONArray().toString());

JSONArray numberArray;
// Create a JSONArray to store all numbers
try {
    numberArray = new JSONArray(oldNumbers);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    numberArray = new JSONArray();
}

/// Loop through the multiautocomplete textview value array
for(int i=0; i < arrayOfString.length; i++)
{
    // Check whether the string contains '%'
    if(arrayOfString[i].contains("%"))
    {
        // Add numbers to the already existing array of numbers
        numberArray.put(arrayOfString[i].split("%")[1]);
    }
}

// Store the complete number array in preference as String
ed.putString("snum", numberArray.toString());
ed.commit();


// To read the numbers after saving
String display = sp.getString("snum", new JSONArray().toString());
System.out.println(display);
```

**Edit 2:**
To get rid of the quotes, convert the preference string to `JSONArray` and iterate it.

```
// To get rid of quotes
try {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(display);

    for(int j=0; j<arr.length(); j++)
    {
        String number = arr.getString(j);
        System.out.println(j+" - numberWithoutQuotes : "+number);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: My bad the error solved using here but the number isnt stored plz help.

Comment: bro the numbers are scuessfully getting stored in the shared preferences..but have a couple of problems.       1)the numbers are stored but they have been stored like[&quote;contactnumber1&quote;,&quote;contactnumber2&quote;&quote;contactnumber3&quote;].. how to get rid of the &quote; at front and back of number and the square braces.            2)after saving the numbers if i want to insert new numbers by replacing the old ones what should be done because the new numbers are getting added but not getting replace.             Thank you for your help bro please help me with these two problems

Comment: the mobile numbers stored in the shared preferences should be used to send an alert SMS to mobiles so plz help me to rectify it.

Comment: Bro i removed the code for oldnumbers, now everytime the data is being stored as new so no worries to the second problem...plz help me with the first one, i dont want to save the whole array with the quote just number1,number2,number3 so that these numbers can be used by SMS application and directly send an alert msg with the push of a button in case of emergency. Thankyou for your help. Really :)

Comment: See the **Edit2** in my answer

Comment: where do i use it...i am getting same number with qoutes...please if u dont mind replace the new code with old. i am not familiar with try catch blocks.

Comment: plz help me with this one problem bro.... i am at the edge of my project completion.

Comment: please bro help me out... i am stuck with this code ...:(

Answer (score 0):

```
The error is coming due below two lines. After spliting you have check the length of array. 

Your Code
if(arrayOfString[i].contains("%"))
           str2 = arrayOfString[i].split("%")[1];


It should be like below.

if(arrayOfString[i].contains("%")){
           String[] str3 = arrayOfString[i].split("%");
if(str3.lenght >=2)
str2 = str3[1];
}
```